# Why is my readline / .inputrc configuration being ignored?

Tags: readline, inputrc

I have a configuration line in my `.inputrc`:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste on  # Insert paste as a string rather than possibly running it
```

This is valid when typed at the command line:

```
bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on'
```

However the variable is not being set when I start `bash v4.4.23`.

Why is this line being ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Put comments on separate lines to configuration.

A comment at the end of a line causes `readline` to silently ignore the *whole line* if the line would otherwise be valid.

---

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax) does say:

```
Lines beginning with a ‘#’ are comments.
```

It doesn't say that a comment will cause an otherwise valid config line to be ignored.

This is strange, because the line:

```
set foobar on  # baz
```

Results in:

```
readline: /home/ravi/.config/readline/inputrc: line 34: foobar: unknown variable name
```

Meaning that lines with a `#` at the end of them are indeed parsed for validity. They're just ignored if they would otherwise be valid.

Comment: Note that it says "lines _beginning_ with `#`".  A line not with a `#` at the start may not be a comment and the `#` and the text after it will be part of the value.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree with you, but when setting a variable to `on # blah` when its valid values are either `on` or `off` some sort of error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The parser for readline doesn't seem to be that good:

```
 $ bind 'set "enable-bracketed-paste" "on" '; echo $?; bind -v | grep 'bracketed'
 0
 readline: "enable-bracketed-paste": unknown variable name

 $ bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste "on" '; echo $?; bind -v | grep 'bracketed'
 0
 set enable-bracketed-paste off

 $ bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on '; echo $?; bind -v | grep 'bracketed'
 0
 set enable-bracketed-paste on

 $ bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on .'; echo $?; bind -v | grep 'bracketed'
 0
 set enable-bracketed-paste off
```

It seems that any string after an option is seen as part of the option (maybe?).

The manual states that comments are **only** at the start of the line, so, I recommend you to stick to that rule. Instead, use:

```
 # Insert paste as a string rather than possibly running it
 set enable-bracketed-paste on
```

Comment: From the last example it seems that anything invalid will return the value to the default value.

Comment: Well, yes, for the `enable-bracketed-paste` option, but that is not the case for `set bell-style off` for example, it stays at the previous value when the line is not understood by readline, not falling to a default value. @TomHale

Comment: `readline`: now with added randomness for increased surprises!